# Former employer is still advertising my name, photo, biography on their website even after 2 months since I left

Tags: management, work-environment, work-experience, employer-relations, employer

I didn't leave on good terms. I was fired due to not being a "good fit" or not fitting in with the culture of the practice. They had hired someone else to replace me and even had that person work there while I was still working there. It's been two months since I left the company, and I currently work at another office which I'm happy at.  They don't have the replacement's info (image, name, bio) on their website currently and they still have my info up.

It irks me that my information is being used to draw in customers when I no longer work there and didn't leave on good terms (especially with the replacement being brought on while I was still working there). I would like them to remove my info as I feel it is misrepresentation and I do not wish to be associated with the company anymore.

How can I effectively word a demand to have my information removed immediately from their website?

Comment: You were not a good fit culturally but I assume you did well enough in your job that they use your image to bring in customers? Or is it you made connections with certain clients and they don't want to lose them

Comment: Getting changes like this  in under 6 months on the average corporate website would be wildly optimistic

Comment: Donna, that ought to have been posted an answer. There are currently no answers, so why leave a comment which is really an answer? If you answer, there is more chance of people seeing it in future and being helped than if you just comment

Comment: @Neuromancer Taking the GDPR laws into consideration in the EU, I think 6+ months would be considered "undue delay" (IANAL). If the OP is in the EU I would suggest to point the company to those laws.

Comment: could you specify which country you are in, as it might be relevant ?

Comment: *What are my options?* - In this case probably qualifies as asking for legal advice.  I believe how you can word a demand letter to remove it is in scope of this site.  However I believe your overall question is probably better suited to https://law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

Remember [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor). Never assume malice when incompetence is a proper explanation.

So I would first assume that their webmaster just forgot to update the website. You might want to send them a polite(!) reminder.

> Dear [former colleagues]
>
> As you know, I've left [company] at [date]. However, I noticed that you did not yet update your website. [url] still shows me as an employee. Please remove my name and picture from your website at your earliest convenience.

When that doesn't help, check what your local laws say about rights to your own image and if there was any clause in your work contract regarding publishing your name and image. When you think that they might be using your likeness illegally, seek legal advise.

Comment: +1 though I think I would change the wording from *at your earliest convenience* to *immediately*.

Answer (score -2):

I think it depends on how far would you like to go with it.
First step would be a email or phone call with request to remove your information from their website.

Are you located in US?
in that case you can give them strict deadline for removing your personal information.
If they do not comply after the deadline, you can go legal route for trading on your credentials without compensation.

As one with hurt feelings from being fired, you can lawyer up and get some money out of them for it